# Postgresql - get counts along with results

Tags: postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, knex.js

I have 2 tables

```
cars
|id|name|car_type_id|

car_types
|id|name|
```

`car_type_id` can be null for a car.

I want to query my db so I can get a list of the car types with the counts of how many cars per `car_type`. The cars with null in car type can be null.

I hope this was clear. But any advice is welcome.

So I am looking to get back something like

```
car_type      | count
car type 1    | 3
car type 2    | 4
uncategorized | 12
```

EDIT:
So I can get the types and their totals using

```
select 
car_type.id,
car_type.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars 
 WHERE cars.car_type_id = car_type.id) as tot
from car_type
```

But this does not give me all those cars with car_type_id of null

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Im not quite sure how to attack this problem to begin with....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer (ie `left`) join from `cars` to `car_types`, but specify `'uncategorized'` as the car_type name where there is no join. Union that with a reverse join that filter *out* matching rows.

```
select 
    coalesce(car_types.name, 'uncategorized') as car_type,
    count(*) as tot
from cars
left join car_types on cars.car_type_id = car_types.id
group by 1
union
select car_types.name, 0
from car_types
left join cars on cars.car_type_id = car_types.id
where cars.car_type_id is null
union
select * from (select 'uncategorized', 0)
where exists (select * from cars where car_type_id is null)
```

fyi, `coalesce()` returns the first non-null value from the list of values provided to it, and all columns are `null` in a left-joined table when there are no matching rows.

Comment: This one is almost perfect but I would also like to return the car_types that have a 0 count

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I do have a question. What is the `group by 1` for?

Comment: @MikeL it means "group by the first column". The alternative is `group by coalesce(car_types.name, 'uncategorized')`, which is a pain to (re)type plus if you change anything in the selected value, you must change it in the group by too. btw, the `group by` list is implied and therefore adding no value by its presence anyway... might as well minimize the inconvenience.

Comment: If I want to add a where clause to this so it only looks where car and car_type is owned by a specific user_id, how would I do this? `EDIT: nevermind, looks like I can add it after from cars`

Comment: I forgot to ask, but I do not get the uncategorized returned once all cars are categorized. Is there any way to always get it back?

Comment: @MikeL that's because if there are no "uncategorized" cars, there will be no data returned. I've added to the query to cater for this. A simpler, better alternative would be to make `car_type_id` not nullable and simply create a car_type with the name "uncategorized", which would take care of everything.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, I will take that into consideration

Comment: I am running the query but not seeing the Uncategorized row when all cars have a car_type_id

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` would do it:

```
SELECT coalesce(t.name, 'uncategorized') car_type, count(*)
FROM cars c LEFT JOIN car_types t ON c.car_type = t.id
GROUP BY t.id;

   car_type    | count 
---------------+-------
 uncategorized |     2
 suv           |     2
 sedan         |     3
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION [ALL]` to combine two `SELECT`s, like

```
SELECT 1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT 2
```

to yield

```
some_column_name
1
2
```

So we can add the `NULL` values separately, like so

```
select 
car_type.id,
car_type.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars WHERE cars.car_type_id = car_type.id) as tot
from car_type
UNION ALL  -- changes begin here, the query above is yours
SELECT NULL, 'unknown', (COUNT (*) FROM cars WHERE car_type IS NULL);
```